# can't use concat for '\'

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I want to save a mediumtext data in my table, here's my code;

```
concat('{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\fs18','1','\par }')
```

it's supposed to be a rtf, but when I run, this is what happen,

```
{
tf1ansiansicpg1252deff0deflang1033{fonttbl{f0fnilfcharset0 Arial;}}viewkind4uc1pardfs181par }
```

it should be like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\fs181\par }
```

the '\' mark disappear, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash (`\`) is used as an escape character: it is a statement that the following character should be handled in a special way. `\r`, for instance, is read as a carriage return, which would explain the newline at the beginning of your result. Many of your backslashes are apparently ignored due to the character after it not meaning anything special.

Use a double backslash (`\\`) where you want a literal backslash. The result will be a single backslash in your output. It works this way because the first backslash is escaping the second, saying that it should be treated specially *as a literal backslash*.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Jonathan said, I have this solution:

```
CONCAT('{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1033{\\fonttbl{\\f0\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial;}}\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\fs18','1','\\par }')
```

Use this as string to insert.

[**Here's the SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3f86/1)